# About Google Sheets that is shared with users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets shared with others. My sheet name is "OrderList". I am looking for a script that grabs the user's email address and inputs into another cell when a user edits the sheet. I have written the following code, however it only returns the sheet owner's Gmail address:

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK1 = 5;
var COLUMNTOCHECK2 = 6;

var DATETIMELOCATION1 = [0,2];
var DATETIMELOCATION2 = [0,3];

var SHEETNAME = 'OrderList'

function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();

if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK1) { 
    var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  var dateTimeCell = 
  selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION1[0],DATETIMELOCATION1[1]);
  dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
  var dateTimeCell1 = 
  selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION2[0],DATETIMELOCATION2[1]);
  dateTimeCell1.setValue(email);
  }
   if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK2) { 
  var dateTimeCell = 
  selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION2[0],DATETIMELOCATION2[1]);
  dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
   }

   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running this `onEdit(e)` you can use [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events), these are great for capturing the data you're trying to achieve. You'll need to set up an onEdit trigger for your project to capture the email address though. The code below should achieve what you're expecting.

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK1 = 5;
var COLUMNTOCHECK2 = 6;

var DATETIMELOCATION1 = [0,2];
var DATETIMELOCATION2 = [0,3];

var SHEETNAME = 'OrderList'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();

    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK1) { 
      var email = e.user.getEmail();

      var dateTimeCell = 
          selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION1[0],DATETIMELOCATION1[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
      var dateTimeCell1 = 
          selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION2[0],DATETIMELOCATION2[1]);
      dateTimeCell1.setValue(email);
    }
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK2) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION2[0],DATETIMELOCATION2[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
    }

  }
}
```

As you can see, I've change your `var email` to use an event object to capture the email address of the user that is editing the spreadsheet:

```
var email = e.user.getEmail();
```

Comment: I changed the code to this, but it just shows the owner and does not show the emails of other editors.

Comment: Read through the [documentation for `getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()), there's a pretty complex set of security policies behind how it works, it's likely that these are stopping you from being able to get the user's email.

Comment: From the documentation I linked you, you'll most likely have to get each user to authorize the script manually.

Comment: when i edit code to "var email = e.user.getEmail();" and run, this message is shown to me: TypeError: Cannot read property "user" from undefined.

Comment: You won't be able to run it manually if you're using event objects as the event objects are only passed when the script runs from the trigger.